# How can I determine if a string contains XML in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given an arbitrary string, how can I determine if it contains XML, and parse it out in a node.js app?

Ex.

`var s = 'hello world <hello type="greeting">world</hello>';`

I've tried [nodexml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodexml) and [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js), but both of them require the entire string to be XML.

Edit for clarity:

Ideally I'd like something like:

```
var s = 'hello world <hello type="greeting">world</hello>';
var parsed = parse( s );
console.log( parsed );
```

```
{
  originalString: 'hello world <hello type="greeting">world</hello>',
  textOnly: 'hello world ',
  js: {
    hello: {
      type: 'greeting'
      '@text': 'world'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `<hello type="greeting">world</hello>` could be HTML. Invalid HTML because the `hello` tag doesn't exist (and still, it's possible I believe now with HTML5), but it could be HTML.
I guess the best way is to have some parent node that specifically mean that the content is XML. Otherwise there is no way to differentiate XML and HTML, and that's just an example.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about differentiating XML from HTML.  I'm more concerned with parsing out the *ML from the string.  See edits.

Comment: Then I guess that @lostsource answer is worth a try :)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer provides you the required parser. You may accept if it satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading your string using [node-htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser)

```
npm install htmlparser
```

Since its parser is forgiving with malformed and partial HTML strings you should be able to load any input and then check for a specific HTML tag in order to determine whether the parsed data returned a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2). **[Demo](http://demos.forbeslindesay.co.uk/htmlparser2/)**

```
npm install htmlparser2
```

A forgiving HTML/XML/RSS parser. The parser can handle streams and provides a callback interface. This is a fork of the htmlparser module. The main difference is that this is intended to be used only with node (it runs on other platforms using browserify).

Tested with the following data:

```
 var input = "Hello This is Bikram"+
    "<hello type="greeting">world</hello>"+
  "<head>"+
    "<meta charset="utf8"/>"+
    "<title>Page Title</title>"+
  "</head>"+
  "<body>"+
    "<a href="https://github.com/ForbesLindesay">"+
      "<img src="/static/forkme.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub">"+
    "</a>"+
"</body>"+
    "Sample answer for stackoverflow!!!"
```

Output:
Refer the [demo link](http://demos.forbeslindesay.co.uk/htmlparser2/) for output

> Performance Measurement:

```
gumbo-parser   : 34.9208 ms/file ± 21.4238
html-parser    : 24.8224 ms/file ± 15.8703
html5          : 419.597 ms/file ± 264.265
htmlparser     : 60.0722 ms/file ± 384.844
htmlparser2-dom: 12.0749 ms/file ± 6.49474
htmlparser2    : 7.49130 ms/file ± 5.74368
hubbub         : 30.4980 ms/file ± 16.4682
libxmljs       : 14.1338 ms/file ± 18.6541
parse5         : 22.0439 ms/file ± 15.3743
sax            : 49.6513 ms/file ± 26.6032
```